# Is there an easy way to fly back to the previous system?

Tags: no-mans-sky

The game, if you follow the Atlas, pushes you forward.  I jumped from system 1 to system 2.  I can not find System 1 again.  I search for an hour.  I tried using a green star as a fixed point so I know I always start in the same orientation.  I have since moved on and I was not able to find system 2 from system 3 but I was able to find system 3 from system 4, so it is possible.

My question: is there an ingame mechanic to make finding previous visited systems easier?

Comment: in the galaxy map you should be able to highlight the systems you already visited by pressing x (instead of tab like the hint suggests). this might help you navigate backwards.

Comment: There is a list of visited systems and planets, you can at least get the name so you know what you're looking for.

Comment: This is a problem I have in Elite: Dangerous, too. I should go post that as another thread...